# Google Place RadarSearch giving INVALID_REQUEST status if types parameter is not provided

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

In the documentation for google places api, it says that only required parameters for the Radar Search Request are **key**, **location** and **radius** .

But when I am giving the following request https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&key=MyKey I am getting "INVALID_REQUEST"   error as follows:

"html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"

Adding types or keyword parameter gives usual result
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&keyword=health&key=MyKey

My goal is to find all addresses in a given location. Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the first request?

Thanks&regards
Chandan.

Comment: Docs says that you have to provide at least one of `keyword`, `name` or `types`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anto. But https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search under Radar Search Request -> Required parameters it only mentions key, location and radius.

Comment: Link you provided says: *A Radar Search request must include at least one of keyword, name, or types. Other parameters are completely optional.* Check **Optional Parameters** after **Required Parameters**